# RegEx positive lookbehind find for repeating results

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to use a positive lookbehind (.net flavor) to replace all single characters surrounded by spaces, when the string contains the text "[must_contain_this_word]" enclosed in brackets like that, but the regex seems to stop after the first match.I want to keep the word in square brackets, and all words that are not single characters. I think I've started in the right direction but am unsure how to get it to repeat the search to the end of the string

My regex:

```
(?:(?=\[must_contain_this_word\])(.*?)\s[a-zA-Z]\s)
```

Replacement: `" $1"`

my input:

```
[must_contain_this_word] text1 a text2 b text3 c
```

my desired output:

```
[must_contain_this_word] text1 text2 text3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *positive lookbehind* based solution:

```
(?<=\[must_contain_this_word].*?)\s+[a-zA-Z](?!\S)
```

Replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5Bmust_contain_this_word%5C%5D.*%3F%29%5Cs%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%28%3F!%5CS%29&i=%5Bmust_contain_this_word%5D%20text1%20a%20text2%20b%20text3%20c&r=).

**Details**

- `(?<=\[must_contain_this_word].*?)` - a positive lookbehind that makes sure there is `[must_contain_this_word]` phrase and then any 0 or more chars other than newline as few as possible immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a single ASCII letter (use `\p{L}\p{M}*` to match any Unicode letter including optional diacritics after it)
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/69mNMb):

```
var pattern = @"(?<=\[must_contain_this_word].*?)\s+[a-zA-Z](?!\S)";
var s = "[must_contain_this_word] text1 a text2 b text3 c";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s,pattern, ""));
// => [must_contain_this_word] text1 text2 text3
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully. Unfortunately I found out we are using PCRE which doesnt like the quanitifer in the lookbehind.. is there a workaround for this?

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/282